# How to hover in CSS

Tags: css, hover

I got an Image which is 400px x 685px. In the website, i set it will only show 200px x 685px. I want to know how to show the whole image when the mouse hover the image and show another half of the image 200px x 685px to 400px x 685px? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think an acceptable solution would be to create a div in your html. In your style sheet (aka - css file) you should define it with `width:200px, height:685px;` the next thing you want to do is to set all divs tags (or any id you give this fella) a `background-image:url("whatever.png")`;
Now, you should also use the `background-position:right (or left, your choice)`.

What will happen so far? Your div will show half an image.
Now you should use div:hover as a new set of rules in your css, and there also use the background-position:left/right (the one you didnt use).

Tell me if it works.

Comment: nothing happen after typing background-postion: left

Answer (score 0):

So I think a part of your css may looks like:

```
.your-class {
    background: url("[the path of your image]");
    background-size: 200px 685px;
 }
```

then for when the mouse hover the image:

```
.your-class:hover {
        background-size: 400px 685px;
 }
```

Note that if you're using the `<img>` tag itself in your .html file, then you should write width and height instead of background-size. Anyway The code above is somehow what developers do in css in this case. But obviously it really depends on how you've structured your HTML with div tags and also the classes you've given to these tags.

Answer (score 0):

you achieve by set

```
 .selector:hover 
  {
     background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
```